# read_excel() function is not working in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to read an excel file in Rmarkdown but it doesn't work and no error is given. The program keeps running endlessly and printing none sense messages! Here is the code (only 1 line):

```
library(readxl)

buoy1_north <- read_excel("buoy1_north.xlsx")
```

These are the console's messages that keeps going forever:

[image]

Here is my dataset (just a normal dataset! maybe Rmarkdown doesn't like * ?)

[image]

My excel dataset has only 5 variables and it can be read with no problem in R script, but it can't be read in Rmarkdown. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I can't see how there would be "no problem" in an R script given this issue in RMarkdown. They should perform in the same way. The messages indicate that `read_excel` is finding the text character * in cells where it was expecting a number.

Comment: @neilfws Exactly I have no idea why Rmarkdown performance is not consistent with the R script. I have no idea what does that expectation mean! I don't see any problem with my dataset.

Comment: @AminShn you can try to manually mention `col_types` argument in `read_excel` and see if it works

Comment: It looks like R has guessed columns D and E are of type double, but is then finding * characters in later rows of those columns. I think this is a data issue, not a RMarkdown issue.